# Best for my counter? An array of objects or a simple object?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

I need to keep track of and display how many times a price point is being used, e.g.: "**$15 (2 options)**" Given that i need to display the price and the count and increment the count each time a new option is added at the given price, should I go with:
[image]

or this:

[image]

*Note: do not pay attention to the field names "array" and "object-priceCount", this is for testing purposes only.*

Comment: Can you explain "price point is being used"? Like when that data is shown or so? Can you provide more details on that ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj being used like "$15 (2 options available)" where two products/services would have been recorded under the 15$ price point.

Comment: I may suggest a totally different solution based on more info: You've got USD which tells me you may also be storing the price point in other currencies - is that correct? I also think more clarity is need on *price point being used*. Are there 15 different products and some of them have a 15 price point and you want to know how many 15 price points are used? Or how many were sold at 15 or... what?

Comment: @Jay Good questions! Indeed, there will be various currencies. But I'll stick to the same price point "numbers" (eg: 15, 25, 49, 99 since they are psychological), so currency code will be appended to each price point on display.
Products & services will be recorded under preset price points (15, 25, 49, 99, 149...). That's what I meant. If there are 12 services under that 25 price point, I want to display: 25$ (12 options). Hope this helps, thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd actually keep a map for these counters, so that you can update an individual counter with:

```
updateDoc(docRef, { 'priceCounts.USD15': increment(1));
```

Comment: Thanks, so does this simple object with a field name "USD15" enables me to display next to the count "USD15" to users too?

Comment: Sure. A map field like this maps to a dictionary or map in most programming languages, and you'd then show the keys of of that map/dictionary to get the `USD15`, etc.